# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful resources for both the GM and the player
- utilities for running meets online
- the site's twitter account
- cool roleplaying events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3222).

Comment: When is the deadline for submitting an ad?

Comment: @EL You have until December 2014 to submit an ad for the 2014 rotation.

Answer (score 27):

[image: Find out the odds]

Comment: My cleaned-up version of [this 2013 ad](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/2727).

Answer (score 18):

[image: Roll20 - Virtual tabletop gaming that tells a story]

Comment: It is usefull. You should try it.

Answer (score 17):

[image: MapTool – For the RP Games you play]

Comment: We have Roll20, seems reasonable to have Maptool too.

Comment: I think we have Roll20 because it was the new hotness last year, but yeah, might as well put Maptool up for votes. I rather like this ad's design.

Comment: Yeah, I only joined with last year already ongoing so I didn’t bother to make the ad then, but I much prefer Maptool over Roll20, personally.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Great RPGs have great worlds!]

Answer (score 10):

[image: RPG.SE Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: +1 It's Fate, it's cyberpunk, it's by an active community member. Clearly relevant to quite a few users' interests.

Comment: Cheers, @Alex :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Scabard - RPG Campaign Manager]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Anime & Manga Stack Exchange]

Comment: Same ad we used last year. No reason to change since it seemed to work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

[image: DieDieDie: an advanced die roller for the modern web]

Comment: I... really don't like the name. ["Die die die" is a common phrase](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22die%20die%20die%22) very strongly associated with wishing awful things would happen to someone/thing.

Comment: That was my idea with it, I figured it would be used for attack rolls.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Comment: Image Credit: [@TildalWave](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/177/6)

Comment: That font is almost impossible to read.

Comment: @KRyan I know you're not an Astronomy regular, but feel free to suggest an alternative here: [Off-site Astronomy community promotion ads](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/161/off-site-astronomy-community-promotion-ads)

Comment: I found the font gave me a second's comprehension trouble, but otherwise I like the ad. The design is striking, and the very clear silhouettes are particularly effective at communicating the site's purpose. A different font would be a big improvement, but I won't withhold my vote for that reason.

Comment: Personally I don't find the font that hard to read, especially within context as is here. I kind of like it actually...

Answer (score -3):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Comment: An alternative ad, if you prefer this design. Image Credit: [@MBR](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/183/6)

Comment: I do much prefer this ad, actually. Blue on black could be better, but ultimately this one is much clearer.

Comment: I really dislike the weird contrast problem in the text. People with low-contrast vision problems won't be able to read your ad without discomfort. Is there any reason why those letters are royal blue instead of white, or at least a very light blue, maybe sampled from the lightest parts of the moon?

Comment: Aesthetically, it would also be improved by swapping the moon and "Ask the Universe" text: the white space would be better balanced, and the viewer's eye would move moon -> radio dishes -> empty-space -> "Ask the Universe", which enhances the call to action and provides an image view-line that is thematically appropriate to radio dishes pointed into space (and your SE) and the implication of answers to be found there (and at your SE).