# How do I list an external resource?

Tags: discussion

After reading through the 5e DMG, I became disgusted with the way magical items are organized. I'm creating a sortable list and will upload to DropBox or something this weekend; my question is, how do I share my work?

Should I post a question like "How do I pick the right magic item?" and then provide an answer myself with a link included?

Answer (score 10):

**Our site doesn't function well as broadcast point**

While your desire to share this helpful tool you've created is laudable, the format of our site and our best practices for questions and answers would tend to look down on that kind of a post and it would likely be voted to close within a few hours.

You could however share it in chat. I'd also suggest submitting it to enworld as they seem to be happening place for any and all 5e homebrew and content restructuring right now.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Joshua this generally is not a good broadcast point. In your case, however, there are some avenues available for you. First, you have to follow some guidelines, because you're (a) providing a link to an external resource, and (b) advertising. Those guidelines are:

- [Avoid link-only answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Your answer must still fundamentally answer the question if the link goes dead tomorrow. We want our answers to still be useful a few years from now. (Some circumstances circumvent this, like tool recommendations, which is perfect for you, but I'll get to that.)

  - If you're sharing your own resource, *please* make sure the link won't go dead within weeks. We would hope the link can last for a few years, or your tool will still be findable after that.
- From [our advertising guidelines](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/behavior): you must disclose your affiliation to the product, and it has to be a good and relevant answer. You should also not be here *primarily* to advertise, but I think you're OK in this regard.

If you can provide a good answer to an existing question following the guidelines above, and a link to your tool would be fitting, you may link to it.

Your best options are probably these (and you can do both):

## Use our community ads

Add a [Community Promotion Ad](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/community-promotion-ads-2014). If we like it, we'll upvote your ad and it will display on our site.

The community ads question is recreated each year (e.g. here's last year's: [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/community-promotion-ads-2013)). That might happen anytime now, so when it gets refreshed you'll have to add it to the new question too.

## Find or create a relevant tool recommendation question.

We have a [tool-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-recommendation) tag for people looking for things that help them do stuff.

Look through it and see if there's a question already asking for this kind of thing. If there is, answer it! If there isn't, you can create your own self-answered question.

### If you go for a self-answered tool-rec...

Self-answered questions, and their answers, ***must*** still meet our quality standards. This *would* go without saying, but people tend to get lazy in this regard when making self-answered questions. Your question must be one that would be considered good quality even if the answer didn't exist (a good answer doesn't justify a bad question), and your answer would hopefully still be good quality as if you were providing someone else with an answer.

To make a good question, pretend your tool didn't exist, but you wanted something like it. What would you ask? What would past-you have said, before you went and made the tool yourself? Maybe something like:

> I don't like the way D&D 5e's magic items are organised. {Explain why, so that we understand what features to avoid. Be brief, don't make it a rant.}
>
> Is there a resource that offers a well-organised magic item list? I'm after these criteria:
>
> {Now explain what you *do* want.}

Then answer it with a link to your tool, describing what it is and how it meets the criteria — that's what the best tool-rec answers tend to do, and what you should probably do anyway if you want people to be interested in your thing.

Bear in mind your question and answer *will* still be subject to the usual moderation by the community at large, and you still need to make sure you meet our quality criteria if you act on this suggestion. People may request improvement, or so on. If you somehow wind up asking a bad tool recommendation, it may get closed, and in most cases someone will instruct you on how you can improve it. (If nobody does, you can ask here on meta what you can do.)